# Why does loop order matter when there's strided prefetching?

Tags: c, caching, prefetch

In C you're told to iterate through a matrix in a row-major order since that's how the arrays are stored underneath the hood and row-major iteration is utilizes the whole cache-line, which leads to fewer cache misses. And indeed, I do see a massive performance difference between row-major and column-major iteration on my machine. Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int getTime()
{
  struct timespec tsi;

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tsi);
  double elaps_s = tsi.tv_sec;
  long elaps_ns = tsi.tv_nsec;
  return (int) ((elaps_s + ((double)elaps_ns) / 1.0e9) * 1.0e3);
}

#define N 1000000
#define M 100

void main()
{
  int *src = malloc(sizeof(int) * N * M);
  int **arr = malloc(sizeof(int*) * N);
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    arr[i] = &src[i * M];

  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
      arr[i][j] = 1;

  int total = 0;

  int pre = getTime();


  for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      total += arr[i][j];

  /*
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
      total += arr[i][j];
  */

  int post = getTime();

  printf("Result: %d, took: %d ms\n", total, post - pre);
}
```

However, modern memory systems have prefetchers which can predict strided accesses and when you iterate through a column you are following a very regular pattern. Shouldn't this allow column-major iteration to perform similarly to row-major iteration?

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of the functionality being available, but of C supporting it. [Here's some GCC documentation about it.](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/prefetch.html)

Comment: Also SIMD optimization is much easier if your loop follows the memory order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cache line has a certain size (for example 64 bytes) and the processor reads and writes complete cache lines. Compare the number of bytes that are processed and the number of bytes that are read and written.

Comment: Correct. In addition, some strided prefetchers have limits on the stride range.